# How do i make an condition if textbox is different than a column in database and display an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have a `textbox`, when the `textbox` is empty I display all the content in `CrystalReport`, else if is not null I display the name of worker that is equal with the `textbox`. It is possible to display 'worker not found' if the `textbox` is different than name from Oracle database? How can I achieve that? I tried something but is not working

```
protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Name.Text == "")
        {
            strSQl = "select * from employees";
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQl, con);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "employees");
        }
        else 
        {
            strSQl = "select * from employees where name ='" + this.ToTitleCase(Name.Text) + "' or surname='" + this.ToTitleCase(Name.Text) + "'";
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQl, con);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "employees");
            Label2.Text = "Employees found";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label2.Text = "error";
    }
    CrystalReport report = new CrystalReport();
    report.SetDataSource(ds.Tables["employees"]);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
}
```

Comment: Check the number of records in your `OleDbDataAdapter` after you attempt to fill it in your `else` block. Psuedo-code, but `if da.Rows.Count == 0 Label2.Text = "Worker not found"; else Label2.text = "S-a gasit angajat";`

Comment: @sab669 `OleDbDataAdapter` doesn't not contain a definition of Rows this is the error

Comment: that's why I called it psuedo-code. Google around to learn how to find how many rows are in your DataSet.

Comment: @sab669 thank you for information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @sab669 for the info, this is the code from your pseudo-code, thank you

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0) {
  Label2.Text = "Employees not found";
}
else {
  Label2.Text = "Employees found";
}
```

Comment: Glad I was able to get you pointed in the right direction, and more importantly you were able to find the solution on your own. Additionally, while I assume this is school work, you should look into [parameterizing your queries](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=parameterized+queries+C%23) rather than concatenating direct user-input into your SQL statements. That's a huge security risk and is **very** easy to protect yourself against.